# Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window'The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, single-sign-on

Here, In my code res is my variable name and i am trying to stringify them 
    using sso  atob but i am not able to do this because of this below error 
    which i am facing.

```
var baseUrl = window.location.origin + '/index.html/login';

    var res = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(atob($stateParams.authUrl.split('\.')
        [1])), null, '  ');
        res = JSON.parse(res);
```

Error: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not 
    correctly encoded.

Comment: What ... why are you using `atob()`? And why are you JSON encoding and then immediately parsing? What is your code trying to do?

Comment: we are trying to do single sign on POC